# Проблема с Ajax на WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

Пытаюсь внедрить ajax фильтр по цене в WordPress, но он упорно не хочет работать, возвращает пустой результат.

Подключаю ajax во фронтэнде так:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 );
function myajax_data(){
    wp_localize_script( 'script', 'myajax', 
        array(
            'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        )
    );  

}
```

Html фильтра

```
<form method="POST" id="filter">

<input type="text" name="cena_min" placeholder="Минимальная цена" />
<input type="text" name="cena_max" placeholder="Максимальная цена" />

<button>Применить фильтр</button>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
</form>
```

js

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url:myajax.url, // обработчик
            data:filter.serialize(), // данные
            type:filter.attr('method'), // тип запроса
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Применить фильтр'); // возвращаеи текст кнопки
                $('#response').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP обработчик

```
function true_filter_function(){

        $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'ID', // сортировка
        'order' => 'ASC' // ASC или DESC
    );


// создаём массив $args['meta_query'] если указана хотя бы одна цена
    if( isset( $_POST['cena_min'] ) || isset( $_POST['cena_max'] ) )
        $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' ); // AND значит все условия meta_query должны выполняться

    // условие 1: цена больше $_POST['cena_min']
    if( isset( $_POST['cena_min'] ) )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'new_price',
            'value' => $_POST['cena_min'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>'
        );

    // условие 2: цена меньше $_POST['cena_max']
    if( isset( $_POST['cena_max'] ) )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'new_price',
            'value' => $_POST['cena_max'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<'
        );

    die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'true_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');
```

В итоге после нажатия кнопки "Применить фильтр" происходит отправка значений, надпись кнопки меняется на "загружаю" и далее опять "Применить фильтр", но в блоке response все пропадает, т.е. он становится пустым. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: А где wp_enqueue_script? приведенный код работать не может.

Comment: Мне вот интересно... Все такие умные, кинулись сразу js исправлять (может и правильно, конечно), но самой сути не увидели. В силу влияния "крутых" фронтендеров народ поголовно стал пихать баттоны, где надо и надо, забывая о том, что обработку клика нужно делать самому. Посему, уважаемый ТС, либо поменяйте вашу кнопку на обычный input type="submit", либо текущей пропишите type="submit", либо напишите сами обработчик, с чего у вас форму должна сабмититься то?

Comment: @DaemonHK Форма сабмиттся, потому что вы плохо знаете html. Откройте стандарт https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html и найдите там абзац "The missing value default and invalid value default are the Submit Button state". Это, кстати, подтверждается и текстом вопроса, из которого видно, что событие submit срабатывает. Прежде чем давать едкие комментарии, предполагающие, что вы самый умный, стоит себя хоть как-то проверять.

Answer (score 0):

Так происходит, потому что в ajax-запросе отсутствует поле action. Не видя этого поля в массиве POST, admin-ajax.php возвращает код 400. Вы получаете пустой ответ с кодом завершения 400. [Инструкция на русском](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

И, кроме того, вы совершенно напрасно пренебрегаете nonce.

**UPDATE**

Ваш js должен выглядеть примерно так

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $(this);
        var data = {
            action: 'myfilter',
            cena_min: $('#filter input[name=cena_min]').val(),
            cena_max: $('#filter input[name=cena_max]').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:myajax.url, // обработчик
            data:data, // данные
            type:filter.attr('method'), // тип запроса
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Применить фильтр'); // возвращаеи текст кнопки
                $('#response').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: >> И, кроме того, вы совершенно напрасно пренебрегаете nonce. Это следующий этап, с которым нужно разобраться, сначала хочется заставить работать код, а потом конечно и проверку делать

Comment: >> Так происходит, потому что в ajax-запросе отсутствует поле action. Вы имеете ввиду action в form? добавляя action в < form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" > ни каких изменений не видно

Comment: У вас в $.ajax внутри data **должно быть** поле action. Читайте документацию. И оно должно быть для вашего кода `myfilter`. Иначе каким чудом WP догадается, что надо передать управление вашему хуку `wp_ajax_myfilter`? Еще раз: admin.ajax.php, который вызывается по $.ajax, смотрит в POST поле action. Если его нет - 400. Если не существует хук `wp_ajax_{action}` - 400.

Comment: Откройте код admin-ajax.php, там все понятно.

Comment: поставил action data:jQuery('#filter').serialize() но результата нет, в консоле браузера нет ни каких ошибок почему то

Comment: Я не понимаю, что вы куда поставили. В документации все прозрачно описано. В консоли и не будет ошибок. Чтобы увидеть код 400, смотрите вкладку Network. Дополнил ответ примерным кодом js.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76392/discussion-between-user242682-and-kagg-design).

Answer (score 0):

В общем с учетом подсказок постарался поправить код

```
    /***Фильтр ajax**/

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 );
function myajax_data(){

    wp_localize_script( 'tc-basejs', 'myajax', 
        array(
            'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        )
    );  

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_action_javascript', 99); // для фронта
function my_action_javascript() {
    ?>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $(this);
        var data = {
            action: 'myfilter',
            cena_min: $('#filter input[name=cena_min]').val(),
            cena_max: $('#filter input[name=cena_max]').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:myajax.url, // обработчик
            data:data, // данные
            type:'POST', // тип запроса
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Применить фильтр'); // возвращаеи текст кнопки
                $('#response').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'true_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');
function true_filter_function(){

        $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'ID', // сортировка
        'order' => 'ASC' // ASC или DESC
    );


// создаём массив $args['meta_query'] если указана хотя бы одна цена
    if( isset( $_POST['cena_min'] ) || isset( $_POST['cena_max'] ) )
        $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' ); // AND значит все условия meta_query должны выполняться

    // условие 1: цена больше $_POST['cena_min']
    if( isset( $_POST['cena_min'] ) )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'new_price',
            'value' => $_POST['cena_min'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>'
        );

    // условие 2: цена меньше $_POST['cena_max']
    if( isset( $_POST['cena_max'] ) )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => 'new_price',
            'value' => $_POST['cena_max'],
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '<'
        );

    die();
}
```

+ HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="filter">

<input type="text" name="cena_min" placeholder="Минимальная цена" />
<input type="text" name="cena_max" placeholder="Максимальная цена" />

<button type="submit">Применить фильтр</button>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
</form>
```

Но по прежнему работает только кнопка (меняет значения) сама фильтрация отказывается работать, полагаю ошибка где то в PHP обработчике, но хоть убей не пойму где? Если кто знает подскажите